# Why is my new object() NULL?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, memory-management

I'm new to Flash and not sure why my new planet object is being considered NULL when I try to set properties to it.
Perhaps I am missing some kind of initialization method I should new the planet in, instead of where I declare my variables?

```
    public class main extends Sprite {
    private var game_container:game_container_mc;
    private var left,up,right,down:Boolean;
    var pt:Point = new Point(303,301);
    var myArray:Array = [pt,pt,pt];
    private var plan:planet = new planet();

    public function main() {
        plan.loc.x = 3;
        plan.loc.y = 3;
         //...etc, error is here^
```

Error: "TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
    at main()"

Cheers

Comment: loc is a point defined in planet as
public var loc:Point;

Comment: Hey, just added the comment. loc is defined in planet as public var loc:Point:

package {
 import flash.display.Sprite;
 import flash.geom.Point;
 import Math;
 public class planet extends Sprite {
  private var kind:int = 0;
  private var mass:Number;
  private var atmosphere:int;
  public var loc:Point;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
package { 
import flash.display.Sprite; 
import flash.geom.Point; 
import Math; 

public class planet extends Sprite { 

             private var kind:int = 0; 
             private var mass:Number; 
             private var atmosphere:int; 
             public var loc:Point;
```

Here you can see that loc is null & not initialized. So either set it here itself.

```
public var loc:Point = new Point();
```

Or later in the main function as:

```
 var locObj:Point = new Point();
 locObj.x=3;
 locObj.y=3;
 plan.loc=locObj;
```

Answer (score 0):

Loc is an object too.

```
 public function main() {
        var Po:Point  = new Point();
        Po.x=3;
        Po.y=3;
        plan.loc=Po;
```

Comment: Makes sense now.. every object I have to declare, I have to new it somewhere. Thanks!

Comment: You are right, i'm not familiar with flash object, but in general in any programming language an object should be declare.